# How do I limit the GUI update to 9th time only in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I stop input from asking data for the 10th time? I am trying to build a board and want X or O to be updated only 9 times for a string that has 10 elements. Element 0 been empty.

It seems I need to figure out a way to stop or break the while loop when test_board[9] != "" (in def space_check():). This position if filled by the first player but the while (in #Test Run) loop is still active and so the user input is requested for the 10th position for the 2nd player.

```
enter code here
#Board
def display_board(board):
    print (board[7] + '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    print (board[4] + '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print (board[1] + '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    pass
```

#Player input slection

```
def player_input():
    marker = ''
#Asking player 1 to choose X or O
    while marker not in ["X","O"]:
    marker = input('Player 1 choose X or O ')     

#Assign Player 2 a marker
    player1 = marker

    if player1 == 'X':
        player2 = 'O'
    else: 
        player2 = 'X' 
return (player1,player2)
```

#Player position selection

```
def user_position():
   
    # variables
    
    #Initial
    position ="WRONG"
    acceptable_range = range(1,10)
    within_range = False
    #Two condition to check Digit or within range
    while position.isdigit() == False or within_range == False:
        
        position = input("Please enter a number (1-10):")
        #Digit check
        if position.isdigit() == False:
            print("Sorry that is not a digit!")
        
        #Range check
        if position.isdigit()==True:
            if int(position) in acceptable_range:
                within_range = True
            else:
                within_range =False
                print("Sorry that is not acceptable range!")
    
    return int(position)
def place_marker(board, marker, position):
    board[position]=marker
    #print (board[position])
    pass

def space_check():
    for i in range(1,10):
        if test_board[i] =='':
            empty_position = True
            #print (f'{i}')
        else:
            empty_position = False
    return bool(empty_position)
```

## Test run

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output()
def test_game_run():
    #get the player input
    player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input()
    
    #get player 1 position
    position_p1 = 0
    position_p2 = 0
    empty_position = True
    counter = 0
    #while empty_position == True:
    #    
        
    while (position_p1 == position_p2 or empty_position == True): #and (counter <8): # need to contunue the game
        print("player 1 choose a position")
        position_p1 = user_position()
        
        place_marker(test_board,player1_marker,position_p1)
        empty_position = space_check()
        
        print("player 2 choose a position")
        position_p2 = user_position()
        
        place_marker(test_board,player2_marker,position_p2)
        empty_position = space_check()
        
       # counter =counter + 1 
            
    #print(f'{counter}')
    
    #step3
    #print position by player 1

    
    print(len(test_board))
```

#function call

```
test_board =['']*10
test_game_run()
display_board(test_board)
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_input(prompt,max_tries,allowed_values):
    for i in range(max_tries,-1,-1):
        result = input(prompt):
        if result in allowed_values:
           return result
        print(f"{i} tries left")
     return "default"
```

Is one strategy for this